# C# ListView Sub Items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to add items to a listView that has 2 columns. When I use the code below it will add an item to the first column and nothing to the second then it will create a new line with nothing in the first one and an item in the second, how do I get them both on the same line? Thanks.

```
listView1.Items.Add(item1);
ListViewItem date = new ListViewItem();
date.SubItems.Add(subitem1);
listView1.Items.Add(date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("some item");
item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "sub item"));

this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Set `View` property to the `Details` to check that everything right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are adding *two* ListViewItems to the ListView.  Make it look similar to this:

```
        var item = new ListViewItem("first");
        item.SubItems.Add("second");
        item.SubItems.Add("third");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
```